# How to get CakePHP to send second submit button when pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cakephp

I have a find form with two submit buttons: cancel and find. They work both as they should when they are clicked. But pressing the enter key, always 'cancel' is submitted. I do not want to change the order of the buttons in the form. I found a solution to prevent submission on 'enter' at all. But I'd like to have submit 'find' on enter. I wrote a JavaScript that calls the click action of the find button when enter is pressed. This works but nevertheless 'cancel' is sent.

What's going wrong?

This is my form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null,array('onsubmit' => 'return submitOnEnter(this);')); ?>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Find.num',array('autofocus'));?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Find.name');?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Find.address');?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td align="right">
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Cancel',array('id'=>'cancel','name'=>'cancel','onmousedown' => 'itsclicked = true; return true;','onkeydown' => 'itsclicked = true; return true;')); ?>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td align="right">
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Find',array('id'=>'find','name'=>'find','onmousedown' => 'itsclicked = true; return true;','onkeydown' => 'itsclicked = true; return true;','onClick'=>"alert('The button was clicked.');")); ?>
    </td></tr>
  </table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
function submitOnEnter(form){
    if(itsclicked){
        return true;
    }
    document.getElementById('find').click();
    return true;
}
```

'itsclicked' is set to false on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

This might not be the absolute answer for your question, but this will help you a lot.

Please use the below code for the cancel button

```
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('Cancel',array('type'=>'button','id'=>'cancel','name'=>'cancel','onmousedown' => 'itsclicked = true; return true;','onkeydown' => 'itsclicked = true; return true;','onClick'=>"cancelFind();")); ?>
```

Then use the JavaScript function for cancel operation:

```
function cancelFind(){
  alert('Do what you want to do!');
}
```

Use the below code for find operation:

```
function submitOnEnter(form){
  alert('Do the find operation here!.');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this doesn't change nothing. I'm using cakephp. The find operation is done in the model. So there must be something going wrong from the form to the model. I'm looking for a way to set up the form so it behaves as I expect.

Comment: I mean to say that, if you don't want submitOnEnter() then just do: return true; instead of alert Ok...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with JavaScript and the way to solve it is not to use JavaScript at all but to understand how these buttons work.

First-off `echo $this->Form->submit(....` doesn't generate what you expect it to generate - it returns ***' elements that can be used to submit, and reset forms'***. Notice the '***submit and reset***'. Check it in the [CakeAPI](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-FormHelper.html#_submit).

You say:

> But pressing the enter key, always 'cancel' is submitted

well of course it is - since Cake will generate an  element for you.

You mitigate this you will need to use **a `<button />` of type *button***. ;) You can do this with:

```
<table>
.....
.....
<tr>
  <td align="right">
      <button type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="right">
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Find',.................... ?>
</table>
```

Now attach a click handler to your new *button of type button*. Find will always be submitted on Enter when focusing the form since it is still an `<input>` tag.
This is so because of something called [Browser (Window) Focus](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus).